# Create Bigquery partitioned table using Python and API

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I would like to create a partitioned table in BigQuery from a Python script using `client.create_table()` but I get the error message

> TypeError: create_table() got an unexpected keyword argument 'time_partitioning'`

Would be great if someone could tell me where I am going wrong.

This is the code I am using:

```
client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json('path/to/key')
...
data_ref = bigquery.DatasetReference(PROJECT_ID, DATASET_ID)
table_ref = bigquery.TableReference(data_ref, new_TABLE_ID)
table = bigquery.Table(table_ref, schema = SCHEMA) 
new_table = client.create_table(table, time_partitioning = True)
```

[This is some documentation I used](http://tylertreat.github.io/BigQuery-Python/pages/client.html#bigquery.client.BigQueryClient.create_table)

Comment: Is there a reason not to use a CREATE TABLE statement instead? I feel like that would be easier. See the [DDL documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data-definition-language).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI solved with

```
client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json('path/to/key')
... 
data_ref = bigquery.DatasetReference(PROJECT_ID, DATASET_ID)
table_ref = bigquery.TableReference(data_ref, new_TABLE_ID)
table = bigquery.Table(table_ref, schema = SCHEMA)
table.partitioning_type = 'DAY' 
client.create_table(table)
```